# Python lambda wrong syntax?

Tags: python, json, lambda

I can't get **how to make this work**:

```
default=lambda obj: return None if isinstance(obj, DataLoader)
```

`default` variable is a param for `json.dumps()` so the code makes it possible to not to rise `TypeError` if the dict that being serialized contains a `DataLoader` object inside.

Comment: That's an incomplete conditional expression, you *have* to add an `else`.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer (if you feel like it). I'm not asking you to choose mine, it's up to you. I'm just telling you in case you wouldn't know or would have forgot. Have a good day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want an `else` clause, and drop the `return`:

```
lambda obj: None if isinstance(obj, DataLoader) else obj
```

A [`lambda` expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) has to return *something*, but they don't need `return`, their one expression is *always* the return value.

A [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) likewise has to produce *something*; what should the expression produce when `isinstance(obj, DataLoader)` is false?

Comment: Also, no `return` in `lambda`.

Comment: @bereal: indeed, I missed that one.

Answer (score 4):

First, when you create a [`lambda` expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda), you have to omit the `return` keyword.

Also the ternary operator (*aka [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)*) work as follow:

```
a if b else c
```

… will return `a` if `b` is `True` and will return `c` otherwise (if `b` is `False`).

You are missing the `else` part.

**In the end, your code should look like that:**

```
default = lambda obj: None if isinstance(obj, DataLoader) else obj
```

Pick what you want your lambda function to return when `obj` isn't an instance of `DataLoader`, here I picked `obj` for you, but it's up to you.

Finally, I added some spaces around `=` as it is the way you should do (As described in the  [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).